# Chocolate mousse for frosting?

Tags: cake

Can you use a basic chocolate mousse as frosting for a cake?  Would it be stable enough or is my layered cake going to fall apart?

Answer (score 3):

My favorite chocolate mousse recipe uses gelatin as a stabilizer.  I've used it as a filling between cake layers and it works really well.  I don't see why you couldn't use it on the outside of the cake as well.

You'll want to keep the cake refrigerated.  I don't know exactly how long it will remain stable, but I've kept it in the fridge for several days without a problem.

Comment: Just a warning -- a chilled cake can be a problem in humid areas.  When you take it out of the fridge, you can get condensation on it which can mess up the frosting (especially if it's more decorative / colored).  You want to let it come back up to room temperature covered, and then unwrap it.

Comment: @Joe That's a very good point.  Thanks!  I recommend a rigid container, if you have one.  I learned the hard way that foil and plastic wrap tend to stick to frosting, making a real mess of it when you unwrap it.  If you have to use plastic wrap, I suppose you could lay it over the ends of skewers stuck in the cake.

Comment: Some frostings will crust up as they dry -- if it does, you can get away with draping it with plastic wrap or similar, but you shouldn't try to tightly wrap it.  If you have a sufficiently large hard-sided container, you're right, it's a hell of a lot easier.